# Converting .obj file to .sdkmesh using MeshConvert tool

Tags: directx-10

DirectX SDK provides a utility that converts .x or .obj file to .sdkmesh, its called meshconvert tool.

But, I tried many times and its not working.

It shows this message "Cannot Load specified input file"
(I input a .obj file named samp.obj and typed "meshconvert /sdkmesh samp.obj".)

Can anyone please help me solve it?

P.S. I'm on windows 7 and inputting the above command in DirectXSDK Command prompt.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you ever find out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have read that the .obj file type listed by MeshConvert.exe refers to a binary form of .x, not the popular Wavefront Object Model format. I'm still looking for a way to do this myself.